# ValidateUsername is read-only | TS with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a small utility function, that I am having some test with Jest and Enzyme on my React-TS project. In a JS file in that project, I get the following error:

```
"validateUsername" is read-only.
```

This is the utility itself:

```
export const validateUsername = value =>
  listUsers()
    .then(({ data }) => {
      if (Array.isArray(data) && data.find(userData => userData.username === value)) {
        throw 'Username already exists';
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw serverErrorResponseUtil(error);
    });
```

And here is the test for it:

```
describe('Validate Username', () => {
  const validateUsernameFn = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    validateUsername = validateUsernameFn;
  });

  it('Should throw an error if the given value exists', async () => {
    try {
      await validateUsername('username');
    } catch (e) {
      expect(e).toEqual('Username already exists');
    }
  });

  it('Accept the data if the passed userName is unique', async () => {
    expect(() => validateUsername('Username is unique')).not.toThrow();
  });
});
```

I get the error here: `validateUsername = validateUsernameFn;`. The thing is this file is a js one. Why am I getting a ts error about read-only. Can you guys help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You may have found the solution already, but the issue is that you import `validateUsername` and then redefine it in `beforeEach()`.

I have no idea why you need the code in `beforeEach()`, but if you want to access initial `validateUsername` + enjoy the benefits of mocking, I'd suggest using `jest.spyOn`.

In `beforeEach()` you can clear mocks between tests, if you need it.